# MVC Perform different methods for different dropdownlist selections

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

**Controller**

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var LeaveType = new SelectList(new[] 
        {
            new { ID = "0", Name = "" },
            new { ID = "1", Name = "Full day leave" },
            new { ID = "2", Name = "Half day AM leave" },
            new { ID = "3", Name = "Half day PM leave" },  
            new { ID = "4", Name = "Time off" }, 
        },
        "ID", "Name", 0);

        ViewData["LeaveType"] = LeaveType;
        return View();
    }
```

**View**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <label class="text-center">Leave Type</label>
        @Html.DropDownList("LeaveType", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
$('#LeaveType').change(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
        if (value == "0") {
            $('#EndDate').closest('.form-group').hide();
            $('#StartDate').closest('.form-group').hide();
            $('#datetimepicker6').closest('.form-group').hide();
            $('#datetimepicker7').closest('.form-group').hide();
            $('#leaveReason').closest('.form-group').hide();
            $('#createBtn').closest('.form-group').hide();
            $('#cancelBtn').closest('.form-group').hide();
        }
        else if (value == "1") {
            $('#EndDate').closest('.form-group').show();
            $('#StartDate').closest('.form-group').show();
            $('#datetimepicker6').closest('.form-group').hide();
            $('#datetimepicker7').closest('.form-group').hide();
            $('#leaveReason').closest('.form-group').show();
            $('#createBtn').closest('.form-group').show();
            $('#cancelBtn').closest('.form-group').show();
            @*@Html.ValueFor(CurrentApplication.)*@
        }
        else if (value == "2") {
            $('#EndDate').closest('.form-group').hide();
            $('#StartDate').closest('.form-group').show();
            $('#datetimepicker6').closest('.form-group').hide();
            $('#datetimepicker7').closest('.form-group').hide();
            $('#leaveReason').closest('.form-group').show();
            $('#createBtn').closest('.form-group').show();
            $('#cancelBtn').closest('.form-group').show();
        }
        else if (value == "3") {
            $('#EndDate').closest('.form-group').hide();
            $('#startDate').closest('.form-group').show();
            $('#datetimepicker6').closest('.form-group').hide();
            $('#datetimepicker7').closest('.form-group').hide();
            $('#leaveReason').closest('.form-group').show();
            $('#createBtn').closest('.form-group').show();
            $('#cancelBtn').closest('.form-group').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#EndDate').closest('.form-group').hide();
            $('#StartDate').closest('.form-group').hide();
            $('#datetimepicker6').closest('.form-group').show();
            $('#datetimepicker7').closest('.form-group').show();
            $('#leaveReason').closest('.form-group').show();
            $('#createBtn').closest('.form-group').show();
            $('#cancelBtn').closest('.form-group').show();
        }
    });
```

My `LeaveType` is a drop down list where users can select what kind of leave they want to apply for (eg. Full day/half day/time off). When they select the value on the drop down list, i want to hide or show certain elements because some may not be required based on the type of leave.

I have a startDate and endDate textbox and for half day, i won't show the endDate textbox but i want to set the endDate to be the same as startDate if the user selects the halfday selection from the dropdownlist. I'm guessing I should have a if else loop and I know how to write the codes but I have no idea where to put it.

Also, when i display the data in a table, my drop down list values are display as the ID. How do I display the Name of the LeaveType instead? All help appreciated ^^ Thanks!

Comment: `else if (value == "2") { $('#EndDate').val($('#StartDate').val()); ..... }`

Comment: Why the line `@Html.DropDownList("LeaveType", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })` as null for collection?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I tried it but it still didn't work :o

Comment: @user1672994 oh is it not supposed to be null?

Comment: @eyeballs, Your `DropDownList()` usage is fine (although its an awful way to do it). What's not working? The code I showed you sets the value of the EndDate to the current value of the StartDate.

Comment: @StephenMuecke oh i see. The value of EndDate doesn't get set/ saved into the database

Comment: When you select a value from the dropdown, does the `StartDate` have a value? I suspect you probably want to handle the `.change()` event of the `StartDate`, and update the `EndDate` if the selection is half day. Although it seems unnecessary to do that in the client. You can just update the `EndDate` to match the `StartDate` in the POST method if its half day (which protects you against a malicious user as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the `change` event of `#StartDate` like following. Hope this will help you.

```
$('#StartDate').change(function() {
     var endDate = $('#EndDate');
     if ($('#LeaveType').val()==2) {
         endDate.val($(this).val());
     }
 });
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much :) @Azim